# resetar valor variavel javascript ao fechar modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal

Boa tarde desenvolvedores,adicionei uma funcionalidade em uma tela de adicionar abas,sempre que clicko no icone de mais ele adiciona uma aba na tela,  quando click em um registro na tabela ele abre o modal para edição,ate ai tudo bem,mas preciso que os valores das variaveis de incremento de abas se percam ao fechar o modal e ao abrir outro registro a variavel volte a ser 1 e não continuar com o valor da aba anterior,eu tentei mudar o valor sempre que abro a quantidade de abas que esse cliente tem,mas o valor não altera,vou deixar um trecho do codigo para você entender melhor.

Codigo que abre as abas

```
   abrirAbas(id)
    
    function abrirAbas(id){

       
        $.ajax({
        url  : '../../../controller/cliente_vendendoController.php',
        type : 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data : {
        "request":"qtd_cotas",
        "id_cliente":id,
        },
        success: function(response){     
    

        for (let index = 1; index <= response.quantidade; index++) {
            if(index >  1){
                      
             $('#addCotaEditar').trigger('click')
         
            }
         
        }  
 
        localStorage.setItem('cota',JSON.stringify(response));
        count   =1
```

PARTE DO CODIGO QUE ADICIONA AS ABAS NO MODAL
var count = 1

```
$(function() {
   $(document).on("click", "#addCotaEditar",function(dados){
      
        console.log("Valor Contador variavel Local" + count)
        $.ajax({
            url: '../_includes/cliente_vendendo/adicionar_cota.php',
            type: "POST",
            
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(retorno) {
             
                window['count'] = window['count']+ 1;
```

tento mudar o valor para 1 sempre que abro apenas as abas que existem,mas o valor da variavel nao muda e continua incrementando,alquem pode me ajudar ? desculpa se não fui claro.

Answer (score -1):

Talvez seja falta de colocar um var antes do nome do elemento:

**var count = 1;**

E deves iniciar ele antes da função, senão, ele fica fazendo parte apenas da função e, por isso, não daria para acessar o elemento fora da função:

```
var count = 1;

    function abrirAbas(id){
        ...
```

Comment: obrigado por responder,fiz a alteração dessa forma,mas quando fecho o registro e abro novamente por algum motivo o valor count fica como 3,era para ser 2 ja que atribui o valor 1 naa mesma,quer seria incrementado mais 1 ao adicionar a aba.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).